# Can I have the Windows 7 taskbar pinned icons change like they do when unpinned?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, icons

I just discovered that if Windows Explorer is unpinned from my taskbar it displays the icon of the currently active folder. This is what I see if it's pinned

[image]

But if it's unpinned I see the current icon.

Downloads:

[image]

Documents:

[image]

C:

[image]

I really like seeing the "correct" icon, and I've noticed this also applies to other programs that have varying icons.

Is there a way I can have explorer pinned, but to see the icons as though it's unpinned?

Comment: Mabey I am missing something, those are the "open" icons for the same item, it is not only the correct icon, but it is the method of display that (in my mind) that would apply. When pinned the Icon showing is for the program(general), when unpinned it is showing the open folder or disk item.    Nice pictures.

Comment: @Psycogeek Yes, but I guess I don't see why the icon should change if it's not pinned. It's the same program, and if I open two Explorer windows, they get grouped together in the taskbar.

Comment: Many of the system icons are stored in hackable Dlls like shell32.dll and in the explorer executable. With a resource hacker they can be changed. some of the problem with that is they are locked (so it takes a bit more effort) and they will be replaced when an update to that particular item comes in.  That would be one way to change what the system shows. That would change it system wide though, it would be worse to show the "program" in all the other locations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer to this question is, unfortunately, "No."

Answer (score 0):

Under my knowledge the answer is "NO" that is because when we "PIN" an app it shows the app icon and not the current active. Usually an app has a constant icon (not like windows explorer).